# Error between scratch org and sandbox: Permission ModifyAllData depends on permission(s): EditPublicReports, EditReports, ManageDashboards

Tags: sandbox, permission-sets, scratch-org

We have a permission set with this metadata:

```
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ModifyAllData</name>
    </userPermissions>
```

Deploying this to a scratch org returns the error:

> Permission ModifyAllData depends on permission(s): EditPublicReports, EditReports, ManageDashboards

The problem is, if I add this line to the permission set:

```
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>EditPublicReports</name>
    </userPermissions>
```

Then I am no longer able to deploy to my **sandbox,** with the error "Unknown user permission: EditPublicReports".

The only stackexchange result for the above error is [this one](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/44704/ant-deployment-error-unknown-user-permission-editpublicreports) which is now entirely out of date.

How can I solve this error so that we can deploy this permissionset both to scratch orgs, and to sandboxes?

Comment: Stab in the dark: does your sandbox have Enhanced Report Folder Sharing turned on? It's on by default in new orgs, but very old orgs may have it turned off.

Comment: We're on service cloud and searching for "folder sharing" in the setup quickfind box returns no results. is there somewhere else I should look?